# Laravel hasMany to a composite table return empty array

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship, laravel-8, has-many

I have 3 tables that connected each other

account_receivables

- account_receivable_id (PK)
- ...

account_receivable_details

- account_receivable_id (PK FK)
- order_id (PK FK)

orders

- order_id (PK)
- ...

[image]

After that, I want to make a relationship like this

```
class AccountReceivable extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'account_receivable_id','event_id','account_receivable_date','account_receivable_description','account_receivable_amount','xendit_id','xendit_status', 'xendit_expiry_date','account_receivable_percentage'
    ];

    protected $primaryKey = 'account_receivable_id';
    public $incrementing = false;

    public function accountReceivableDetail()
    {
            return $this->hasMany(AccountReceivableDetail::class, 'account_receivable_id', 'account_receivable_id');
    }
}
```

But when I called AccountReceivable like this it returns an empty array of accountReceivableDetail

```
public function getRiwayatById(Request $request, $id){
    $riwayat = AccountReceivable::where([
        'account_receivable_id' => $id
    ])->with('accountReceivableDetail')->first();
    
    return $riwayat;
}
```

[image]

Do you know why it returning an empty array when I actually have data in the table?

[image]

[image]

Comment: check foreign and owner keys in relations.

Comment: @KaleemShoukat but I have put the same key (the key have same name)

Comment: @SanMargo As far as I know, if an AccountReceivable has many AccountReceivableDetails, then the account_receivable_id column in AccountReceivableDetails can't have multiple ids because that column is a PK. If you want a relationship like that, create a PK id for AccountReceivableDetail like account_receivable_detail_id. CMIIW

Comment: @adhiskara I think it was called by composite key? so we have two column as primary key

Answer (score 0):

You are passing owner key wrong Corrected function is:

```
 public function accountReceivableDetail()
 {
       return $this->hasMany(AccountReceivableDetail::class, 'account_receivable_id', 'id');
 }
```

If account_receivables table and account_receivable_details table both have one to one relation then you should replace hasMany() to hasOne()

Comment: Sorry if I haven't explained too fully, actually one AccountReceivable has many AccountReceivableDetail (because it contains detail to connect to order)

Comment: Then only change the function just like I have written.

Comment: uhm, but I have rename the key so both have the same name (account_receivable_id)